# how do i fix angular and ejs code to for statement

Tags: angularjs, ejs

I want to use the for statement to get all the values ​​of the no column in the DB

my angular code

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('BasicCtrl20', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("/concept_db")
   .then(function(response) {
     $scope.gridOptions4 = response.data;
   });
  });
```

and my ejs code

```
 <% for (var i=0; i < {{gridOptions4[i].name}}; i++) { %>

<div class="{{gridOptions4[0].class}}">

  <div class="gallery-item">

    <a href="{{gridOptions4[0].main_href}}">

      <div class="gallery-item-image"> <img ng-src="{{gridOptions4[0].imgsrc}}"></div>

    </a>

    <div class="gallery-item-description">

      <p align="center">{{gridOptions4[0].name}}</p>



    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<% } %>
```

but result 
[image]

How do i fix?

Comment: Did you try with EJS-Lint plugin? Maybe it will lint you what does't work

Comment: what is mean???

Comment: `if the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint`